# DllImport for a group of imported functions

Tags: c#

Is there any way to specify same DllImport attribute for a group of external functions, any analogue to `extern "C" { … }` ? I don't like to repeat it for every function declaration :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The only way to avoid it is to write a ref class wrapper in C++/CLI.  Which lets you #include the C header file directly.  Your C# project can then simple add the reference to the C++/CLI generated assembly.  This avoids lots of accidents, you now get compiler error messages when you declare something wrong, but isn't exactly competitive with the pinvoke declarations if cutting lines of code is your only objective.

Comment: Great answer, Hans. There are a couple times where this would have saved a lot of trial/error on the PInvoke signatures.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, the attribute has to be on each function.